# ifelse returns NA instead of expected value

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
P1 <- c("UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
P2 <- c(NA, "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", "UP", NA, NA, NA, NA)
P3 <- c(NA, NA, "Normal", "Normal", NA, "Normal", "Normal", NA, "Normal", "UP", NA, "UP", NA)
P4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", NA, NA, NA, "UP", "UP", NA)
P5 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Normal", NA, NA, "Normal", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "UP")
df <- data.frame(P1, P2, P3, P4, P5)
```

I am trying to add a column with the status based on the values of P1:P4 columns. But for some reason, it returns NA instead of "ANTI" or "UNKNOWN"

```
df['status'] <- ifelse(df$P1=="UP" | df$P2 == "UP", "PRO", 
                          ifelse(df$P3=="UP" | df$P4 == "UP", "ANTI", "UNKNOWN"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifelse` will need you to specify `!is.na(df$var)` which can become quite verbose. If you aren't married to using `ifelse`, a more parsimonious solution may be:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(status = case_when(
    P1=="UP" | P2=="UP" ~ "PRO",
    P3=="UP" | P4=="UP" ~ "ANTI",
    TRUE ~ "UNKNOWN"
  ))

#      P1   P2     P3     P4     P5  status
# 1    UP <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 2    UP   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 3    UP   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 4    UP   UP Normal   <NA> Normal     PRO
# 5    UP   UP   <NA> Normal   <NA>     PRO
# 6    UP   UP Normal Normal   <NA>     PRO
# 7    UP   UP Normal Normal Normal     PRO
# 8  <NA>   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 9  <NA>   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 10 <NA> <NA>     UP   <NA>   <NA>    ANTI
# 11 <NA> <NA>   <NA>     UP   <NA>    ANTI
# 12 <NA> <NA>     UP     UP   <NA>    ANTI
# 13 <NA> <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     UP UNKNOWN
```

If you do need to use `ifelse` statements:

```
df3 <- df
df3['status'] <- ifelse((!is.na(df$P1) & df$P1=="UP") | (!is.na(df$P2) & df$P2 == "UP"), "PRO", 
                       ifelse((!is.na(df$P3) & df$P3=="UP") | (!is.na(df$P4) & df$P4 == "UP"), "ANTI", "UNKNOWN"))

# > df3
#      P1   P2     P3     P4     P5  status
# 1    UP <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 2    UP   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 3    UP   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 4    UP   UP Normal   <NA> Normal     PRO
# 5    UP   UP   <NA> Normal   <NA>     PRO
# 6    UP   UP Normal Normal   <NA>     PRO
# 7    UP   UP Normal Normal Normal     PRO
# 8  <NA>   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 9  <NA>   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
# 10 <NA> <NA>     UP   <NA>   <NA>    ANTI
# 11 <NA> <NA>   <NA>     UP   <NA>    ANTI
# 12 <NA> <NA>     UP     UP   <NA>    ANTI
# 13 <NA> <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     UP UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Whoops - a remnant from copying and pasting the `ifelse` command from the OP - thanks for the comment! Have edited it

Answer (score 3):

Please find one possible alternative solution using the library `data.table`

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, status := fcase(P1 =="UP" | P2 == "UP", "PRO",
                            P3 =="UP" | P4 == "UP", "ANTI",
                            default = "UNKNOWN")][]
```

- Output

```
#>       P1   P2     P3     P4     P5  status
#>  1:   UP <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#>  2:   UP   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#>  3:   UP   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#>  4:   UP   UP Normal   <NA> Normal     PRO
#>  5:   UP   UP   <NA> Normal   <NA>     PRO
#>  6:   UP   UP Normal Normal   <NA>     PRO
#>  7:   UP   UP Normal Normal Normal     PRO
#>  8: <NA>   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#>  9: <NA>   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#> 10: <NA> <NA>     UP   <NA>   <NA>    ANTI
#> 11: <NA> <NA>   <NA>     UP   <NA>    ANTI
#> 12: <NA> <NA>     UP     UP   <NA>    ANTI
#> 13: <NA> <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     UP UNKNOWN
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There has been alternative provided to you in other answers. I'll explain why you get those `NA` values in `status` column. It is because of `NA` values in your data.

Consider this small example -

```
x <- c(1, 2, NA, 1)
x == 1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE    NA  TRUE
```

if you have `NA` in the data and you compare it with `==` it will return `NA` as output which in turn returns `NA` in `ifelse`. A simple and quick fix without changing a lot of your code would be to replace `==` with `%in%` which returns `FALSE` for `NA` values.

```
x <- c(1, 2, NA, 1)
x %in% 1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Implementing it in your case you get -

```
df <- transform(df, status = ifelse(P1 %in% "UP" | P2 %in% "UP", "PRO", 
                          ifelse(P3 %in%"UP" | P4 %in% "UP", "ANTI", "UNKNOWN"))

#     P1   P2     P3     P4     P5  status
#1    UP <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#2    UP   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#3    UP   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#4    UP   UP Normal   <NA> Normal     PRO
#5    UP   UP   <NA> Normal   <NA>     PRO
#6    UP   UP Normal Normal   <NA>     PRO
#7    UP   UP Normal Normal Normal     PRO
#8  <NA>   UP   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#9  <NA>   UP Normal   <NA>   <NA>     PRO
#10 <NA> <NA>     UP   <NA>   <NA>    ANTI
#11 <NA> <NA>   <NA>     UP   <NA>    ANTI
#12 <NA> <NA>     UP     UP   <NA>    ANTI
#13 <NA> <NA>   <NA>   <NA>     UP UNKNOWN
```